# Powershell Cross Domain Control

Tags: vbscript

How would code look like for accessing another domain in AD and creating a user!

NON-CMDLET's! .NET or VB Script only!

I Have an account on the other domain which I can use to create this use ron the other domain.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't run VBScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299773.aspx).

In powershell you need to load assembly for working with it:

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")
```

the code looks like that in msdn link.